# Visual Studio - .exe file install all used dll files

Tags: c#, dll, visual-studio-2015, installation, exe

**History:**

I changed something in my Visual Studio project.

**Problem:**

Now, when I build the `.exe` file and install it on my PC, the destination folder contains all of the `.dll` files I used in my project. I changed from *Community Edition* to *Enterprise Edition*, but when I build it with the *Enterprise Edition*, the problem still occurs.

The installed application works fine, but I don't want to see "System.Collections.dll" in the folder with the `.exe`(executable) file.

I don't see anything uncommon in the last SVN commit.

What may I have missed?

Comment: I made your question more readable (I hope) and highlighted many keywords. I also exchanged the order of the 'Editions' to improve the comprehensibility.

Answer (score 0):

Check the References in the Solution Explorer. Single click every single referenced assembly and make sure that "Copy Local" (which may be named differently - I'm using German Visual Studio) is set to `false` for the framework assemblies and any other assembly that you do *not* want in `\bin\debug`.

Comment: Im not writing about \bin\debug. I mean Program Files\Company Folder\Product Folder, destination folder of the installed .exe file.

Comment: You are not writing about **how** you install the application. That would be an important detail, because some of the installers that integrate with Visual Studio take all the output files for the project. In that case, the setting I wrote about is relevant. If you use Visual Studio Installer Projects, there's an additional "exclude" option for the automatically added references in the Solution Explorer for the setup project itself. And while we're at it: "History: I changed something" is **not** helpful. It would be helpful to tell us **what exactly** you changed.

Comment: The problem occurs because inside the project I placed class that contain tests derived from xunit. Thanks for help.